# Add not null constraint on a whole table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I am having that logging table, that i want every column in it not null. I can't figure out a way other than `:null => false` constraint on all the columns one by one. Is there a better way to do this. i am using rails 5 with PostgreSQL database.
here is the migration:

```
class CreatePurchaseLogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :purchase_logs do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, :null => false
      t.date :created_date, :null => false
      t.integer :plan_id, :null => false
      t.integer :amount_paid, :null => false
      t.string :currency, :default => 'sek', :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to set "global" options at the table level for all columns. The only available parameters to `create_table` would be `:primary_key`, `:id` and `:options` and none of them do what you want.

I would use the shorthand hash notation `null: false` instead of `:null => false`

Also `t.timestamps` include `created_at` so you would not need the `created_date` column.

And, `user_id` and `plan_id` can be better set up using the column type as `references` or `belongs_to`

```rb
class CreatePurchaseLogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :purchase_logs do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :plan
      t.integer :amount_paid, null: false
      t.string :currency, default: 'sek', null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `t.references` defaults to `null: true`. So the example should read `t.references :user, null: true`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference

Comment: You are right. you mean `t.references :user, null: false` there at the end right?

Comment: Ooops! Yeah I meant false